# How to write a result from generator into text file?

Tags: python-3.7

I have generated a str with for loop , but i can't display the same thing outside the for-loop or write the result into a text file

Im using phyton 3.7.4 currently

```
r = open('book_list.txt','r')  
lines = r.readlines()
books = dict((line.strip().split(':') for line in lines))
r.close()

for k,v in books.items() :
    remain = str(k+':'+v)
print(remain)
```

instead for displaying all the key and value , it just display the last key and value

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `remain` variable at each iteration of the for loop. This is why it shows only the last one. You should instead append to the string each new key-value pair. Since you didn't provide the content of the `book_list.txt` I made myself a fake dictionary to test it out.

```
books = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}

remain = ""
for k,v in books.items():
    remain = remain + str(k+':'+v) + '\n'
print(remain)
```

This will print:

```
key3:value3
key2:value2
key1:value1
```

So your final code should be:

```
r = open('book_list.txt','r')  
lines = r.readlines()
books = dict((line.strip().split(':') for line in lines))
r.close()

remain = ""
for k,v in books.items():
    remain = remain + str(k+':'+v) + '\n'
print(remain)
```